# Regular Expression in Java. Splitting a string using pattern and matcher

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to get all the matching groups in my string.
My regular expression is `"(?<!')/|/(?!')`". I am trying to split the string using regular expression pattern and matcher. string needs to be split by using /, but '/'(surrounded by ') this needs to be skipped. for example `"One/Two/Three'/'3/Four"` needs to be split as `["One", "Two", "Three'/'3", "Four"]` but not using .split method.

I am currently the below

```
      // String to be scanned to find the pattern.
      String line = "Test1/Test2/Tt";
      String pattern = "(?<!')/|/(?!')";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      
      if (m.matches()) {
         System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
        
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
```

But it always saying "NO MATCH". where i am doing wrong? and how to fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you meant to call `find()` instead of `matches()`?

Answer (score 3):

To get the matches without using split, you might use

```
[^'/]+(?:'/'[^'/]*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `[^'/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `'` or `/`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `'/'[^'/]*` Match `'/'` followed by optionally matching any char except `'` or `/`
- `)*` Close group and optionally repeat it

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sETsta/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/sRFli7)

```
String regex = "[^'/]+(?:'/'[^'/]*)*";
String string = "One/Two/Three'/'3/Four";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
One
Two
Three'/'3
Four
```

**Edit**

If you do not want to split `don't` you might also use a pattern to not match `/` but only when surrounded by single quotes

```
[^/]+(?:(?<=')/(?=')[^/]*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iUk7gV/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
String line = "One/Two/Three'/'3/Four";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("('/'|[^/])+");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

output:

```
One
Two
Three'/'3
Four
```

Comment: shortest pattern 

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
  String line = "One/Two/Three'/'3/Four";
  String pattern = "([^/]+'/'\d)|[^/]+";

  Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  
  boolean found = false;
  while(m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group() );
     found = true;
  } 
  if(!found) {
     System.out.println("NO MATCH");
  }
```

Output:

```
Found value: One
Found value: Two
Found value: Three'/'3
Found value: Four
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple pattern matching all desired `/`, so you can split by them:

```
(?<=[^'])\/(?=')|(?<=')\/(?=[^'])|(?<=[^'])\/(?=[^'])
```

The logic is as follows: we have 4 cases:

1. `/` is sorrounded by `'`, i.e. `'/'
2. `/` is preceeded by `'`, i.e. `'/`
3. `/` is followed by `'`, i.e. `/'`
4. `/` is sorrounded by characters other than `'`

You want only exclude 1. case. So we need to write regex for three cases, so I have written three similair regexes and used alternation.

Explanation of the first part (other two are analogical):

`(?<=[^'])` - positiva lookbehind, assert what preceeds is differnt frim `'` (negated character class `[^']`

`\/` - match `/` literally

`(?=')` - positiva lookahead, assert what follows is `'`\

[Demo with some more edge cases](https://regex101.com/r/RctN65/1)